# Two type of adblock profiles in Chrome

Tags: youtube, google-chrome, google-chrome-extensions

in Chrome, I modified Adblock extension with its filter to hide duration and title of the videos in youtube to prevent spoilers.

The problem is that sometimes I don't want to use my modified setting, to do that, I should add comment sign in some lines of Adblock filter which is annoying and time-consuming.

Is there any way to quickly switch Adblock settings or maybe defining accounts on Adblock?

PS: If the question is not clear, let me know so I add more info.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about using Chrome, not about using a web application.

Comment: instead of closing, it is better to migrate the question to the proper forum, maybe superuser?